# Trying to use HTTPS Get request [Node.Js] for rest of project

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use an API to get IP address that gets a local city. Then using the city name from the IP address to run threw another API to get the local weather when they visit my cite. This is my first NodeJs project I am attempting on my own. I wanted one API call to get a JSON object that contains the info of the IP address. So far I have only gotten undefined or Promise {pending}.

I have looked up using async/await functions and using the fetch() function instead of https.
I have also tried wrapping the get request around a new Promise function but still with undefined results. In this project I have the main app.js and a functions.js in attempt to keep clean code. I am completely lost.

first try.

```
function getRawData(){
const https = require('https');
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    https.get('https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=' + ipApiKey, res => {
        console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);

        res.on('data', d => {
            let data = JSON.parse(d);
            let cData = data.city
            resolve(cData);
        }).on('error', e =>{
            reject('error'. e.message);
        });
    });
});
```

}

```
function getIp(){
getRawData().then(data =>{
    return data;
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

}

A different type of code I tried:

```
async function getIPAddress(){
let data = await fetch('https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=' + ipApiKey)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {return res});

return data;
```

}

when I would call any of the functions on the main app.js I would not get the JSON data I need. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer using the fetch function in a stacked call.

```
function requestIP(url){
    return fetch(url)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(json => json);
} 

fs.requestIP(ipUrl).then(data =>{
        const part ='hourly,alerts,minutely';
        const lat = data.lat;
        const lon = data.lon;
        const name = data.city;
        const apiKey = process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY;
        const units = "imperial";
        const urlWeather = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + '&units=' + units + '&exclude=' + part + '&appid=' + apiKey;

        fetch(urlWeather)
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(json =>{
            let todayW = json.current;
            let tomW = json.daily[0];
            let n1Day = json.daily[1];
            let n2Day = json.daily[2];
            let todayDate = fs.todaysDate();

           res.render('home', {               
                CR: fs.getCopyRights(), 
                dayDate: todayDate,
                cityName: name, 
                todayT: Math.floor(todayW.temp),
                todayI: todayW.weather[0].icon,
                tomT: Math.floor(tomW.temp.day),
                tomI: tomW.weather[0].icon,
                next1T: Math.floor(n1Day.temp.day),
                next1I: n1Day.weather[0].icon,                
                next2T: Math.floor(n2Day.temp.day),
                next2I: n2Day.weather[0].icon,               
            });
        });
    });
```